# How to fetch a Path Object from FileChooser JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

I'm trying to fetch a Path Object like this:

```
private Path file;
private String fileContent;
private Parent root;

@FXML
public void handleOpenFileAction(ActionEvent event) {       
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open a File");
    this.file = Paths.get(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage()).toURI());

    try {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(this.file, Charset.defaultCharset());

        EditorController editorController = new EditorController();
        editorController.openEditor(lines);

    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

However, I get a NullPointerException when I try to output the String List in another method in the EditorController class like this:

```
@FXML
public TextArea textareaContent;

public Parent root;

public void openEditor(List<String> lines) throws IOException {
    this.root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/HassanAlthaf/Editor.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(this.root);

    Stage stage = new Stage();

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Editting File");
    for(String line : lines) {
        this.textareaContent.appendText(line + "\n");
    }
    stage.show();
}
```

This is exactly what I get: http://pastebin.com/QtzQ9RVZ

The EditorController.java:40 is this code: `this.textareaContent.appendText(line + "\n");`

The TextEditorController.java:38 is this code: `editorController.openEditor(lines);`

How do I fetch it correctly and then show it on my TextArea? Note that I want to use `java.nio` and not `java.io`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the way you are getting the file, the issue is you have two different instances of `EditorController`. When you execute `FXMLLoader.load(...)`, the `FXMLLoader` creates an instance of your controller class for you and populates the `@FXML`-annotated fields. So *that* instance has `textAreaContent` initialized, but the instance you create with `new EditorController()` (and on which you are calling `openEditor`) does not.

Refactor it like this:

EditorController:

```
@FXML
public TextArea textareaContent;

@FXML
private Parent root;

public void openEditor(List<String> lines) throws IOException {
    Scene scene = new Scene(this.root);

    Stage stage = new Stage();

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Editting File");
    for(String line : lines) {
        this.textareaContent.appendText(line + "\n");
    }
    stage.show();
}
```

And add an `fx:id="root"` attribute to the root element of Editor.fxml.

Then do

```
@FXML
public void handleOpenFileAction(ActionEvent event) {       
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open a File");
    this.file = Paths.get(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage()).toURI());
    // note the slightly cleaner version:
    // this.file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage()).toPath();


    try {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(this.file, Charset.defaultCharset());

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/HassanAlthaf/Editor.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        EditorController editorController = loader.getController();
        editorController.openEditor(lines);

    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the root element of Editor.fxml?